# Meaning of 寄せる in this context

Tags: meaning, words

I am having some trouble grasping the meaning of 寄せられる in this context. While the most common meaning of 寄せる that I see is something akin to "to approach", it is clearly varied in meaning contextually, as I see it often and am unclear on exactly what it implies. Here's the passage:

> しかし、 企画に対して、「 社会が苦しい」「 読んで生きるのが楽になりました」 という感想が思った以上に**寄せられて**います 。そうした決断は難しいようです.

Comment: It seems to me the project needed a lot of opinions from the audience. Then the project has gathered a lot of comments from the audience. The inbox of the project has been approached by the mails whose the audience's comments such as (「 社会が苦しい」「 読んで生きるのが楽になりました」). I have no idea about "そうした決断は難しいようです."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you read the beginning of the [Huffington Post article](https://www.google.co.jp/amp/m.huffingtonpost.jp/amp/2017/08/22/kiriya%20interview_a_23158043/) which you quoted, you can see the project consisted of a survey.

You can even find a synonym for the 寄せる in the first two sentences of the article itself:

> ハフポスト日本版が6月からスタートさせた「だからひとりが好き」の企画で掲載した、中学・高校で感じた「同調圧力が苦痛だった」という記事に**寄せられた声**だ。
>
> **こうしたメッセージ**がたくさん**届き**、同じ悩みを抱えた人たちがいかに多いかを実感した。

The word simply means "gathered", "received".

And you can find the definition in the [dictionary](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/227809/meaning/m0u/) too:

> ５ 意見・情報などを送り届ける。手紙・文章などを送る。提供する。「回答を―・せる」「便りを―・せる」

Answer (score 1):

From [goo辞書](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/227809/meaning/m0u/), 寄せる has the following meaning:

> ５ 意見・情報などを送り届ける。手紙・文章などを送る。提供する。「回答を―・せる」「便りを―・せる」

Which means to send options, information or letter, article.

寄せる + られる becomes 寄せられる, which is the passive form of 寄せる.

So the original sentence is:

> ...... opinions like 「 社会が苦しい」「 読んで生きるのが楽になりました」 are sent (to the organizer) more than expected.

Comment: `to send options`-- opinions ですかね・・